# angularjs/routing doesnt navigate to sub pages

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, computer-science

I have created a simple application in angularjs .

The main page have three links when I click on one of the them its content should appears . but nothing happened when i click .

This code of the main page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <head>
    
        <script src="javascript/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="javascript/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="javascript/main.js"></script>
    
    
    </head>

<body ng-app="myApp">

    This is main page
    
                <p><a href="#/">Main</a></p>

                <a href="#red">Red</a>
                <a href="#green">Green</a>
                <a href="#blue">Blue</a>

                <div ng-view></div>



</body>
</html>
```

And this is red.html code

```html
           
<section>

     <h2>Hellow in the red world</h2>
        <p>This red page is just for testing</p>
     

</section>
```

green.html

```html
      
       
<section>

     <h2>Hellow in the green world</h2>
        <p>This green page is just for testing</p>
     

</section>
```

blue.html

```html
      
       
<section>

     <h2>Hellow in the blue world</h2>
        <p>This blue page is just for testing</p>
     

</section>
```

And finally this is javascript code

main.js

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "main.html"
    })
    .when("/red", {
        templateUrl : "red.html"
    })
    .when("/green", {
        templateUrl : "green.html"
    })
    .when("/blue", {
        templateUrl : "blue.html"
    });
});
```

Could you explain what is the problem , please

Comment: chabge your href to like this **#/red** and not **#red**

Comment: it works on both sides with your code .. i tried 
#/red and #red  .. they both work .. 

i think the problem caused by the 'angular-route.min' file ..